# Adding subview and bringing to front, but still not showing

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a simple Xcode app with a slide out side panel on the press of a button. I know there's many tutorials, but for various reasons I haven't found any that do what I specifically need.
The first step I tried to take is to have a new view pop up (just completely on top of my first VC) on button press, but I'm having problems.

The following function is being called when my button is pressed:

```
let otherVC = OtherViewController()
self.view.insertSubview(otherVC.view, at: 0)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(otherVC.view)
```

OtherViewController is set up in the Storyboard, and I know it's viewDidLoad function is called with the above code...I just cannot figure out why absolutely nothing happens, and the other VC doesn't show up. Is there anything else I should be doing that will achieve my desired result?

Comment: Add viewcontroller as childViewController. 3 lines of code : addChildViewController(otherVC); view.addSubview(otherVC.view); otherVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

Comment: Do `UI-Debugging` to see your view bounds and whether your view is in the View-hierarchy or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call a View Controller By just initiating in like any other object the view from the storyboard is not attached to it

Instead,

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main) 
let otherVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OtherViewController") as! OtherViewController
```

In addition to this you have to assign a Storyboard Id to the viewController in the storyBoard.

[You have to add the Storyboard ID here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ4dy.png)

After that you should look into UIView Containment for further help

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Using this method, will it be possible to have it be a side panel (only taking up part of the screen)?

Comment: Yes but you have to adjust the frame of the view accordingly, Assuming you want to add a side menu like the one found in android, i would recommend a library https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu instead of reinventing the wheel. The library has a doc section that you can look into. Hope this gives you some where to start from.